# Text file to the hex

Tags: c

I have a text file containing hex codes

```
00000000 4f909390
00000002 5e456783
00000003 3fe52341
```

I need to program the embedded device with the above hex values in my_file.txt .
However, when I read the above file and print them, I see the above hex values in text were totally different and I understand that the txt data were converted to hex format.

```
void print_file( )
{
char source[1000000];

FILE *fp = fopen("my_file.txt, "r");
UINT32 size = ftell(fp); /* get the size */
if(fp != NULL)
{
    while((symbol = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        strcat(source, &symbol);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
   for ( UINT32 i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    printf( "%02x", buffer[i] );
}
```

**The above code displays the hex converted text format and displays me**

```
3030303030303030203466393039333930a303030303030303
2203565343536373833a3030303030303033203366653532333431.
```

This is intact with the text to hex conversion that I checked in online.

**The desired printout should be**

```
00000000 4f909390
00000002 5e456783
00000003 3fe52341
```

What is the right to read the hex values in text by itself and not being converted from ASCII to hex ?Thanks in advance.

Comment: `strcat` will have issues if there is no '\0'

Comment: Are both of the numbers on each line hexadecimal, and what does the first number mean?

Comment: Try `man strtol`.

Comment: (You've got it somewhat backward: the "conversion" you are observing is the effect of *not* converting textual hexadecimal numbers to machine numbers.  The library function you need to use is [`strtoul`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul).  You will probably also want [`getline`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline).  DO NOT attempt to use `scanf` for this, it will only end in tears.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what you want, but I *think* you are trying to read a text file containing two columns of numbers, both in hexadecimal.  This represents an array of 32-bit words which will be written to the onboard memory of a peripheral device.  I am guessing that the first column is an address and the second column is a value to be written at that address.  I don't know what you want written to addresses that aren't listed in the file.

A logical way to represent this file in memory is with an array of two-element structs:

```
struct memory_word
{
    uint32_t addr;
    uint32_t value;
};
```

You can parse that from a line of your file using `strtoul`:

```
int
parse_line(struct memory_word *buf, const char *line,
           const char *fname, size_t lineno)
{
    const char *p;
    char *endp;
    unsigned long n;

    errno = 0;
    p = line;
    n = strtoul(p, &endp, 16);
    if (endp == p || !isspace(*endp) || errno || n > (unsigned long)UINT32_MAX) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: invalid address\n", fname, lineno);
        return -1;
    }
    buf->addr = (uint32_t)n;

    p = endp;
    n = strtoul(p, &endp, 16);
    if (endp == p || !isspace(*endp) || errno || n > (unsigned long)UINT32_MAX) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: invalid value\n", fname, lineno);
        return -1;
    }
    buf->value = (uint32_t)n;

    p = endp;
    while (isspace(*p)) p++;
    if (*p) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: junk after record\n", fname, lineno);
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And you can read the entire file by calling that in a loop:

```
struct memory_word *
read_memory_file (const char *fname)
{
    struct memory_word *values = 0;
    void *ovalues;
    size_t nvalues = 0;
    size_t avalues = 0;

    char *linebuf = 0;
    size_t linesz = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "rt");
    if (!fp) {
        perror(fname);
        return 0;
    }

    while (getline(&linebuf, &linesz, fp) > 0) {
        nvalues++;
        if (nvalues > avalues) {
            avalues = (avalues == 0) ? 16 : avalues * 2;
            ovalues = values;
            values = reallocarray(values, avalues, sizeof(uint32_t));
            if (!values) {
                perror("realloc");
                free(ovalues);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        if (parse_line(&values[nvalues-1], linebuf, fname, nvalues)) {
            fclose(fp);
            free(values);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    if (ferror(fp)) {
        perror(fname);
        fclose(fp);
        free(values);
        return 0;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return values;
}
```

([`reallocarray`](http://lteo.net/blog/2014/10/28/reallocarray-in-openbsd-integer-overflow-detection-for-free/) is not part of the C standard, but it should be.  You can get a copy from the link.)